# Cannot update model because "id already exists"

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I am new to Django and I am trying to use `update_or_create` in the `serializer.create()`.

However, when I send a request with an existing id for customer, gift or subscription, it shows "id already exists" and does not proceed.

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there a completely different way to do this?

```
class SubscriptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
        fields = ['id', 'plan_name', 'price']


class GiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gift
        fields = ['id', 'plan_name', 'price', 'recipient_email']


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subscription = SubscriptionSerializer(required=False)
    gifts = GiftSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = [
            'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'subscription',
            'gifts']


class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ['customer']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        customer_data = validated_data.pop('customer')

        subscription_data = customer_data.pop('subscription')
        gifts_data = customer_data.pop('gifts')

        customer, created = Customer.objects.update_or_create(**customer_data)

        Subscription.objects.update_or_create(customer=customer, **subscription_data)

        for gift_data in gifts_data:
            Gift.objects.update_or_create(customer=customer, **gift_data)

        record, created = Record.objects.update_or_create(customer=customer, **validated_data)

        return record
```

Error is HTTP 400 Bad request

```
{
    "customer": {
        "id": [
            "customer with this id already exists."
        ],
        "subscription": {
            "id": [
                "subscription with this id already exists."
            ]
        },
        "gifts": [
            {
                "id": [
                    "gift with this id already exists."
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": [
                    "gift with this id already exists."
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a valdiation issue. `to_internal` validates your data and raises this exception. Your nested data/relationships cause this error. I use [drf-writable-nested](https://pypi.org/project/drf-writable-nested/) so solve this problem.  You can either override `to_internal` to remove the id of each nested data or you pass through your data at `to_internal` without validation. What `drf-writable-nested` do is it deletes all related data and recreates them. Therefore, an error doesn´t occure.

Answer (score 0):

**`update_or_create`** needs to know which fields are unique, and which fields should be updated on an `IntegrityError`.  To specify the fields to update, add your arguments via the **[`defaults`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)** keyword.

For example, your customer model might look like this:

```
customer_id = customer_data.pop('id')

customer, created = Customer.objects.update_or_create(
    id = customer_id, 
    defaults = customer_data,
)
```

Comment: After updating the code, I am still getting the HTTP 400 Bad request that I added in the question